# How to I get Eclipse to work with the SVN server?

Tags: ftp, svn, eclipse

Could anyone help me out a bit? I've downloaded Eclipse for JS and I'm currently investigating if it could be a great tool at my work.

Right now I'm using NPP text editor with the FTP plugin to edit files on out web server. After editing is done I do some SVN commands (committing/updating) in a putty window to the same server.

I imagine Eclipse could do it all? If so, how?

Comment: So what do you really want to do? *Window > Open Perspective > Other > SVN Repository Exploring* gives you the ability to add your remote repository to Eclipse. You can then check out these remote files to your machine, edit them locally, and commit them back to the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) is an eclipse module that allows you to manage your repositories directly through eclipse ;)